# Get the last minute dated lines from list

Tags: bash, shell, awk, date, sort

If I have an input file with a list of users and their dates they were last signed in, how can I select with a `sort | awk` function the last minute lines?

The dates are written in a `+%H:%M:%S` format.

Example:

```
George 12:00:15 
Max    12:01:03 
Kate   10:32:54 
Adam   08:21:47 
Andrea 12:00:10
```

Current date is `12:01:04`

Outcomes of an if function would be 1st, 2nd and 5th lines

Comment: An example would be better.

Comment: example added to main question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `bash` and using GNU `date` (default on most Linux systems), you can do this:

```
threshold=$(( $(date -d 12:01:04 +%s) - 60 ))
paste file <(awk '{ print $2 }' file | date -f - +%s) |
  awk '$3 > '"$threshold"' { print $1,$2 }'
```

Or to preserve formatting as per the example in the question:

```
threshold=$(( $(date -d 12:01:04 +%s) - 60 ))
paste file <(awk '{ print $2 }' file | date -f - +%s) |
  awk '$3 > '"$threshold" |
  cut -c 1-15
```

Output:

```
George 12:00:15
Max    12:01:03
Andrea 12:00:10
```

For a real example you can also make the date '1 minute ago' (as per Gnouc's answer). The first line would be:

```
threshold=$(date -d '1 minute ago' +%s)
```

Comment: That's really over-engineered.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, well that's definitely true! I never realised `gawk` could compare time strings though.

Answer (score 1):

With `GNU date` and `awk`:

```
awk -F'[ :]+' -v l=$(date -d '1 minutes ago' "+%H:%M") -v c=$(date "+%H:%M") '
    $2":"$3==l || $2":"$3==c
' file
George 12:33:15 
Max    12:33:03 
Andrea 12:33:10
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{t=strftime("%T",systime()-60)}$NF >= t'
```